# Is it normal behaviour to show the non-subset endpoints in Istio

Tags: istio

When subsets are used in both `DestionalRule` and `VirtualService` I see the following endpoints when looking at the debug information.

Does it mean that Istio sees the non-subset endpoints as valid endpoints even thought I'm trying to force it not to route traffic through to them ?

`./istioctl pc clusters apps-onboarding-service-55dd78f64b-c62jf -n apps
apps-onboarding-service.apps.svc.cluster.local                 6585      -          inbound       STATIC
apps-onboarding-service.apps.svc.cluster.local                 6585      -          outbound      EDS
apps-onboarding-service.apps.svc.cluster.local                 8080      -          inbound       STATIC
apps-onboarding-service.apps.svc.cluster.local                 8080      -          outbound      EDS
apps-onboarding-service.apps.svc.cluster.local                 6585      v1         outbound      EDS
apps-onboarding-service.apps.svc.cluster.local                 8080      v1         outbound      EDS`

Cant find any information on the documentation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsets, like v1, that you declare in a DestinationRule are "additional" endpoints that you can route traffic to. Even if you have defined subsets, you can still send traffic to the original non-subset endpoint if you want to, but if you have a VirtualService with a rule that sends 100% of the traffic to the v1 subset, no traffic will go to the non-subset endpoint.